# Updating the user information in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a sample crud application in React. I have an AddUser component and User Component. All the user details are stored in the UserComponent (i.e i'm storing the details in the state).

I'm having a requirement to update the existing user (i.e when I click on the edit button the details should appear on the text box of the AddUser Component and when I click on the submit after making changes those will be saved in the user state). 
I have found out a way to pass the user details from the user component to AddUser component(i.e using the props).

How can i show the details of the user in the text fields of the AddUser Component? Following code is inside the render method of the AddUser Component.

```
<div>
  <form id="theForm" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label >Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' aria-describedby="nameHelp" onChange={this.handleChange} value={user.name} placeholder="Enter Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label >Age</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" aria-describedby="ageHelp" onChange={this.handleChange} value={user.age} placeholder="Enter Age" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label >Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" aria-describedby="addressHelp" onChange={this.handleChange} value={user.address} placeholder="Enter Address" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Following code is in the render method of the User Component.

```
<div>
  <h1 align="center">Crud Application</h1>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Name  </th>
        <th> Age   </th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {userlist}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <AddUser AddUser={this.AddUser} edituser={this.state.users}/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to your question.

The AddUser component must take the selected user as a editUser. In the table that displays the user list upon selecting the user for which you wish to edit have a state variable which holds the current selected user.

Pass that data across to AddUser which for readability purpose can be changed to AddEditUser.

**UserPage.jsx**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import AddEditUser from './AddEditUser'
import UserList from './UserList'

const [userList,setUserList] = useState([])
const [currentUser,setCurrentUser] = useState()

const updateList = (data, editFlag) => {
  let newList = [...userList]
  if(editFlag) {
    newList = userList.filter(item => item.id !== data.id).concat([data])
  } else {
    newList = userList.concat([data])
  }
  setUserList(newList)
}
return (
  <>
    <UserList userList={userList} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} />
    <AddEditUser user={currentUser} updateUserList={updateUserList} />
  </>
)
```

This is a simple example that you can use.
Based on your use case you can modify what you change ,how you update etc.